# How to get browser window width in Vaadin 10 in server-side Java code

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

In Vaadin 8, I can get the size of the window like this:

```
Page.getCurrent().getBrowserWindowWidth();
```

In Vaadin 10, `Page` appears to no longer have the `getBrowserWindowWidth` method.

What is the proper way to determine the width of the browser window in Vaadin 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no proper feature for this in Vaadin 10. We have two open tickets related to this feature: one about [making generic information available](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/3657) and one specifically about [the window size](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4320).

The best way of doing something that depends on the browser size is probably to implement that part using either JavaScript or a CSS Media Query. If you really need to know the size on the server, you'd need to use `Page.exectueJavaScript` to manually extract the numbers in the browser and pass them back to the server using e.g. `@ClientCallable` on a component method.

It should also be pointed out that even if this is implemented, it wouldn't work exactly as well as in Vaadin 7 and 8 because those versions slow down the page bootstrap to wait for e.g. sizing information to be available before running `UI.init`, whereas Vaadin 10 will construct the initial UI contents even before the browser has had time to send the sizing information to the server.

Comment: Do you have code or link for how to do the work around you propose? "use Page.exectueJavaScript to manually extract the numbers in the browser and pass them back to the server using e.g. @ClientCallable on a component method." (I am a Vaadin beginner)